# send facebook message using mobile application on Qt

Tags: javascript, qt, facebook-graph-api, mobile, qml

I have a QML application and I am using functions in Javascript to "communicate" with Facebook Graph API. I have succeeded to post on my friend's wall but Now I want to send him a message to his inbox(private message). I noticed that Graph API doesn't support this So is there any other way to send the message? does Facebook offer any payed api that may help me ?!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Facebook inbox and chat share the same Facebook backend , in fact , as you know , we could call it chat if online , inbox if offline

So to send message you should refer to Facebook chat docs
It requires an XMPP authentication and it can be done with some Qt/C++ glue to the QML UI 
see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/